# How can I use Array.prototype.filter with multiple logical OR || expressions?

Tags: javascript

I want to filter an object based on key or value using `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`, but when I try to use logical OR || I can't do what I want. Is there a good solution without introducing another method or loop?

```js
const object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const object4 = Object
                 .fromEntries(Object
                                .entries(object1)
                                .filter(([key, val])=>key!=="a"||val!== 2));
                                                  // logic goes wrong!


console.log(object4);
// { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } I want { c: 3 }, filter any key with "a" or value with 2
```

I want a proper boolean OR, if any of its arguments are true, it returns true, otherwise it returns false. I have read JS does something weird, but how to sort it?

Comment: Your explanation of OR is exactly the behavior that you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have *is* a proper boolean OR.

`Array.prototype.filter` calls the function for each element of the array, and *if the function returns true,* it is included in the resultant array. This is probably where your confusion lies.

Let's simulate your condition on each entry:

- ["a", 1]: `"a" !== "a" || 1 !== 2` -> `false || true` -> `true`, item is included
- ["b", 2]: `"b" !== "a" || 2 !== 2` -> `true || false` -> `true`, item is included
- ["c", 3]: `"c" !== "a" || 3 !== 2` -> `true || true` -> `true`, item is included

As you can see, the boolean OR is working exactly as you've described. You're getting the correct behavior already.

If you want to exclude `a` and `b`, you're likely looking for **boolean AND** `&&`, as you want *all* conditions to be true for the item to be a candidate for inclusion in the result array.

See here for demonstration:

```js
const object1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const object4 = Object.fromEntries(
                  Object.entries(object1).filter(
                    ([key, val])=>key!=="a"&&val!== 2
                  )
                );


console.log(object4);
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the operation you're looking for, you need the logical *AND* operator, not *OR*.

```
key !== "a" && val !== 2
```

Alternatively, you could express it with *OR*, by negating the entirety of the expression, using positive comparisons instead of negative ones.

```
!(key === "a" || val === 2)
```

Comment: [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) - takes me back to CS101

Comment: @Klaycon I see the same errors being made over and over in questions here. I feel that the lack of formal CS education is a big reason for this, and I worry about the state of software that results. But maybe this isn't the place for me to vent....

Comment: @Barmar I definitely see what you mean. As a counterpoint, I knew several students in my graduating class that graduated still not having a firm grasp on the basics of writing their own code - and there are so many resources online these days for those interested to teach themselves everything. Even if you were to force every programmer through formal education, there's no forcing them to actually learn the concepts they get exposed to. I share your concerns about what this implies of the state of software, though...

Comment: @Klaycon Of course, education is no guarantee of anything. But it's more likely to produce qualified programmers than self-teaching.

Comment: FWIW - I am self taught, and did not take CS101 or the equivalent.  :)

Comment: @Klaycon Not everyone has the luxury of doing a CS degree, it does not mean they can't become excellent. Some people learn in class, and others here on stack overflow. I know it was a dumb mistake, but I learnt my lesson now! No need to lament the state of SW, it is just people making their dumb mistakes in public instead of a classroom. Learning from the mistakes is all that counts!

Comment: @Sumomo I think one of my comments was deleted. I was arguing for exactly what you're saying - I am also self taught. There's nothing wrong with making mistakes, as long as the mistakes are discovered before they manifest as bugs in important software. That was what I meant about being concerned about software, since it's kinda necessary for those who are self taught (and those who want to program but not really learn) to make software via some trial and error